# how to use primary and foreign keys in SQL ALchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following two tables. `User` and `Project`.
I need `User_ID` and `name` to be projected in Project table columns `user_ID` and `User` respectively but i couldn't achieve it.

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    User_ID = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20))
    project = db.relationship('Project', backref='proj')

class Project(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    user = db.Column(db.String(50), db.ForeignKey("user.name"))
    UserID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.User_ID"))
    customer = db.Column(db.String(50))
    lead_office = db.Column(db.String(50))
    phase = db.Column(db.String(50))
```

Comment: `User.name` is not a key (primary or unique), so it cannot be the target of a foreign **key** constraint. Having both in `Project` would be redundand anyway, since you can get the other with a join, and can introduce anomalies where a project references 2 different users through the 2 fk references.

Comment: Note also that if `User.User_ID` is unique then you can use that as the primary key and you don't really need a separate `id` column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ( it worked for me in similar project):

```
class User(db.Model):
    User_ID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20))

class Project(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    id_user = db.Column(db.String(50), db.ForeignKey("User.User_ID"))
    customer = db.Column(db.String(50))
    lead_office = db.Column(db.String(50))
    phase = db.Column(db.String(50))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).